# android shared preferences & bundle vs shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, bundle

So i have been bundling my data between my activities just fine and recently started to save my data  using shared preferences but now i'm wondering if it would be easier on the phone if i saved and loaded shared preferences between the activities or if bundling my data between them and using shared preferences to save it when they close the app is a better choice?
My data i'm using is just simple data like a few ints strings and Boolean data.

Comment: what about using preference in saving and bundle in transfer data between activities ??

Comment: that's what i am doing i was wondering if it would be better to do one way or the other.

Comment: it will depend on your case if the data huge  , i think reading it directly from shared is best from transferring the object between activities but if it simple data like you say i think doesn't mater , the two way is the same performance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using SharedPreferences anyways because you have to keep the values when the app is closed, then just use SharedPreferences all of the time.

However, to save storage space on the user's phone, use a bundle if you only need to share the data between activities and it can be scrapped after the app is closed.

Answer (score 3):

Bundles are for used mainly for passing data between activities. If the data that you're storing is in the form of settings for example, then you're better off using sharedpreferences. If you are storing more data than just a couple of ints and what have you, you should use a SQLite database.

Answer (score 2):

To communicate between activities you can use an Bundle, but if you have a large amount of data i suggest the use of preferences.
To preserve your data when the app is closed use **[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)** or a [DataBase implementation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

[**Android Saving Data**](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html)